# Cannot boot in Ubuntu 13.04 on Windows 8

Tags: 13.04, windows-8

I am running Windows 8, and when I try to select Ubuntu in the boot menu, I get a screen telling me that it cannot load. There is some sort of error that is as follows:

File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr

Status: 0xc000007b

Is anyone familiar with this error.

By the way, I am sorry if this question is a repeat of another one.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**
The error message you got means you tried to install Ubuntu inside Windows (via the Wubi installer).
The problem is that Wubi is incompatible with GPT (preinstalled Windows8 use GPT).

**Solution:** install Ubuntu the standard way, on its own partition. (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall )